# Матрица на assembler

Tags: ассемблер, матрицы, emu8086

Нужна помощь. У меня есть код, в котором матрица переносит строку 7 в 7 столбец, но матрица заполняется так 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0, проблема возникла в том что нужно сделать так чтобы заполнялась матрица так 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, и соответственно менялось 7 строка и 7 столбец правильно.  Ниже код:

```
include 'emu8086.inc'
stack segment
  dw 128 dup(0)
ends

data segment
  row db 0ah
  column db 0ah 
  memory db 100 dup(0)
ends

code segment

InitMatrix proc
  lea bx, memory
  xor cx, cx
  mov cl, row
  rows:
    mov dx, cx
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, column
    columns:
      mov [bx], cx
      dec [bx]
      inc bx
    loop columns
    mov cx, dx
  loop rows
ret
InitMatrix endp

PrintLineMatrix proc
  pop ax
  pop cx
  pop bx
  push ax
printMatrix1:
  mov ax, [bx]
  add ax, 30h
  mov dl, al
  mov ah, 2
  int 21h
  inc bx
  putc ' '
loop printMatrix1
ret
PrintLineMatrix endp

PrintMatrix proc
  xor cx, cx
  mov cl, row
  putc 10
  putc 13
printMatrixRows:
  push cx
  lea bx, memory
  xor ax, ax
  mov al, row
  sub ax, cx
  xor dx, dx
  mov dl, column
  mul dl
  add bx, ax
  push bx
  xor ax, ax
  mov al, column
  push ax
  call PrintLineMatrix
  pop cx
  putc 10
  putc 13
loop printMatrixRows
ret
PrintMatrix endp

Transp proc
  lea cx, memory
  xor ax, ax
  mov al, 6
  xor bx, bx
  mov bl, column
  mul bl
  mov bx, ax
  add bx, cx
  xor dx, dx
  mov dl, 6
  add dx, cx
  xor cx, cx
  mov cl, row
  circle1:
    push cx
    mov al, [bx]
    push bx
    mov bx, dx
    mov cl, [bx]
    mov [bx], al
    pop bx
    mov [bx], cl
    inc bx
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, column
    add dx, cx
    pop cx
  loop circle1
ret
transp endp

start:
  mov ax, data
  mov ds, ax
  mov es, ax
  xor ax, ax
  call initMatrix
  print "Original matrix:"
  call printMatrix
  call transp
  print "Changed matrix:"
  call printMatrix
code ends
end start
```

Вот фото результата:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Помогите исправить пожалуйста.

Comment: скажи это обязательное условие писать это на мертвом диалекте? я просто когда вижу 16-битный код у меня невольно возникает вопрос "кто эти люди которые требуеют писать на нем программы? зачме они это делают? что за черные сердца стучат в их груди?"

Comment: Вы не сможете помочь с этим ?

Comment: Ну вообще, да, задание нужно написать на 16- битном коде

Comment: извини 16 бит я возможно знаю хуже чем ты..я бы сперва перевернул матрицу, в стек а потом поменял столбец со срокой.

Comment: у меня была такая идея, но не получалось реализовать её